# How do I get my google calendar event's ID into the right format for the Calendar API to read in my script?

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I'm trying to write a script that will do both: 1) update an existing event's dates and title on my Google calendar, based on the dates provided in my sheet AND 2) send the updated dates by email to the event's guests (so the event on their calendars is updated).

I was able to successfully update my event's dates and title using CalendarApp.getEventById(eventId). However, I'd *really* like the event notifications to resend to each guest when the dates of the event have updated. This doesn't seem possible to do using CalendarApp (if it's possible, please tell me how!). After struggling with this in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387766/how-do-i-send-updated-dates-for-an-event-thats-already-created-on-my-google-cal), I'm now trying to use Calendar.Events.patch to both update the event and send the update to all the event's guests.

The **problem I keep encountering** is that the eventId, as logged in my sheet by my createEvent script, is in a format ending in "@google.com." This format is read just fine by CalendarApp, but cannot be read by Calendar.Events.patch. I've tried encoding it to base64, since that seeems to be the format looked for by Calendar.Events.patch, but I think I'm still missing something.

When I run the code below, the error returns "API call to calendar.events.get failed with error: Not Found."

```
function updateEvent(calendarId, eventId, email) {
  var vSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var vS = vSS.getActiveSheet();
  var eventId = vS.getRange("R2").getValue(); //R2 is the cell where my eventId is logged

//My attempt to encode my eventId to base64
  var base64data = eventId;
  var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(base64data,Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);

  var vEventName = vS.getRange("M3").getValue();
  var newstartTime = vS.getRange("M5").getValue();
  var newendTime = vS.getRange("M6").getValue();
  var event = Calendar.Events.get('example@gmail.com', encoded);
  if(event.attendees) {
    event.attendees.push({
      email: email
    });
  } else {
    event.attendees = new Array({email: email});
  }
  event = Calendar.Events.patch(vEventName, encoded, {
    start: newstartTime,
    end: newendTime,
    sendUpdates: "all"});
}
```

I suspect the encoded eventId is off a few characters or something, since that seems to be the case when I run the @google.com eventId through [this encoding tool](https://www.base64encode.org/). I just don't know enough to fix it.

Please understand that I'm extremely new to writing scripts and I've already been struggling with this issue for well over a week. I think I learned a lot after the last question I posted, since now I have a better understanding of my exact problem, but I still don't know the fix. I'm trying to teach myself how to do this by reading the questions on this website, reading [Google's information](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch#parameters) (which I unfortunately largely don't understand), and watching YouTube videos. If I'm asking too much of the script, please let me know.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample value of ``var eventId = vS.getRange("R2").getValue();``?

Comment: The value in "R2" will always look something like this: 1c0tqtn56c1tdo1i0fus66f53g@google.com. The leading numbers and letters change depending on the ID Google assigns to the event. "@google.com" has always remained the ending. I tried pulling just those leading numbers and letters into a separate cell, then encoding just those, but it still didn't work. Any idea what I've missed?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about the value of ``eventId``. When I saw your script, I noticed that there is a modification point at ``Calendar.Events.patch()``. Please use as ``Calendar.Events.patch(resource, calendarId, eventId)``. About this, can I ask you about the value of ``vEventName``, ``newstartTime`` and ``newendTime``?

Comment: Thank you for helping! I'm not sure I understand how to use Calendar.Events.patch(resource, calendarId, eventId). What is the "resource" here? I tried Calendar.Events.patch(event, 'example@gmail.com', encoded), as well as many variations of this and the script is still unable to find the event I'm trying to update. To answer your question: vEventName = the text found in cell M3 (what I'd like to appear as the title of the event, such as "Ethiopia Limu"), newstartTime = 6/10/2019, newendtime = 7/30/2019. The dates are formatted as dates in the cells.

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, ``resource`` is the request body of [Events: patch method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch). By the way, I could understand about the values of ``eventId``, ``vEventName``, ``newstartTime`` and ``newendTime``. As the next step, in your script, when ``event`` was retrieved by ``Calendar.Events.get('example@gmail.com', encoded);``, ``event`` is overwritten by ``event = Calendar.Events.patch(vEventName, encoded, {``. ``event`` dose nothing. So in this situation, can I ask you about what you want to do?

Comment: It sounds like I'm probably not using Calendar.Events.get and Calendar.Events.patch quite correctly. Maybe "event" is being used in a redundant way? I want to 1) give the code directions for where to find the calendar and event, then 2) for the code to change ("patch") the event name and start/end dates and email attendees the updated event. I thought my main problem was the form in which my eventId appears, so I'm trying to encode that into a form that the script can understand. But perhaps this isn't my code's only problem? I'm really a beginner with this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to propose a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve an event using event ID.
- You want to update an event and send an email to users.

  - You want to modify the event name, start and end time of the event.
- `eventId` is `1c0tqtn56c1tdo1i0fus66f53g@google.com` which is a text value.
- `vEventName` is `Ethiopia Limu` which is a text value.
- `newstartTime` is `6/10/2019` which is a date object.
- `newendTime` is `7/30/2019` which is a date object.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, it seems that the scripts for retrieving the event and updating the event are different. So in this modification, there were separated.

  - You can see the event at the log, when the script is run.
  - The event is updated.
- About the event ID, you can use `1c0tqtn56c1tdo1i0fus66f53g` of `1c0tqtn56c1tdo1i0fus66f53g@google.com` as the event ID.

When these are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function updateEvent(calendarId, eventId, email) {
  var vSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var vS = vSS.getActiveSheet();
  var eventId = vS.getRange("R2").getValue();
  var vEventName = vS.getRange("M3").getValue();
  var newstartTime = vS.getRange("M5").getValue();
  var newendTime = vS.getRange("M6").getValue();

  var eid = eventId.split("@")[0]; // Added

  // Retrieve event
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eid);
  if(event.attendees) {
    event.attendees.push({
      email: email
    });
  } else {
    event.attendees = new Array({email: email});
  }
  Logger.log(event)

  // Update event
  var resource = {
    start: {dateTime: newstartTime.toISOString()},
    end: {dateTime: newendTime.toISOString()},
    summary: vEventName,
  };
  Calendar.Events.patch(resource, calendarId, eid, {sendUpdates: "all"})
}
```

#### Note:

- If an error related to `date` and `time` occurs when the event is updated, please confirm whether `newstartTime` and `newendTime` are the date object, respectively.

#### Reference:

- [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch)

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and all the notes. I believe I understand what the code is doing. I ran your script above after confirming all details, but received only the error: "Response Code: 404. Message: Not Found." It doesn't give me any details. I confirmed the formatting on each piece of data is exactly as you specify in your notes. I'm at a loss as to why it isn't working, unless we're back to whether this form of the eventId can be read by this particular `Calendar.Events.patch`. Is this something I still need to encode to base64? Or was I on the wrong track with that?

Comment: @Adrienne Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About the error of ``Response Code: 404. Message: Not Found.``, I cannot replicate your situation. When the values in my answer are used for ``updateEvent()``, no error occurs. So can you provide your current script and the flow for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm about your current issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thanks, Tanaike! It's working. Awful /facepalm moment when I went back to the code and realized I hadn't changed `calendarId` to be the Id of my calendar. It's obviously Monday here with a lot going on. Thank you so much for helping me find a solution! It's perfect. I'd quite honestly given up on it ever being possible. You've been so much help with all your explanations too. I understand all of this much better now. Thank you. =)

Comment: @Adrienne Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.